# Android ViewFlipper, how to use it correctly? It is slow and laggy

Tags: android

How can I use a ViewFlipper correctly?

A have a layout file, with a ViewFlipper. I included 7 layouts in there.

Using this code:

```
    mFlipper = (ViewFlipper) ((Activity) mycontext).findViewById(R.id.flipper);
    mFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mycontext, R.anim.slide_left_in));
    mFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mycontext, R.anim.slide_left_out));
    mFlipper.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```

and then:

```
mFlipper.setDisplayedChild(viewID);
```

but it is very slow, and laggy. sometimes it runs fast, but more time it is laggy and slow. why?

update: all of my layout's background picture is a big texture background with FILL_PARENT and transparent png.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because

> all of my layout's background picture is a big texture background with FILL_PARENT and transparent png.

Try to remove that background image from all those inner layouts and set it to the root one (`ViewFlipper`?).